# Sort documents in Mongodb query by dates closest to a field

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, date

I have a collection of documents in mongodb that represent past and upcoming events.  There are two date fields in the document, 'start' and 'end' that are bson ISODATE objects.  I am doing a find query that gets all of the events that have ended no more than 3 days ago.

```
db.events.find({'end': {'$gte': datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=3)})
```

How can I sort the response of this query based on the time (and date) between today and the end datetime of the events.  In other words, events that ended 2 days ago should occur at approximately the same position as events that will occur 2 days from now.  This is important because I do not want to first display all the events that already occurred nor do I want to display events that are happening furthest in the future first either.

Comment: Do you want to sort based only on time, not on date?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what this order would look like. "events that ended 2 days ago should occur at approximately the same position as events that will occur 2 days from now" is a little vague.

Comment: Basically I imagine it working like an absolute value function but for dates.  So if we were sorting integers x in Z greater than -3 based around the value 0 we would take abs(x) which would give us an order 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... Now imagine that x is the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort by the difference in time between today and the end date of the event. So if you had one event tomorrow, one event yesterday and one event the day before, the order you want them in are:

1. event tomorrow
2. event yesterday
3. event day before yesterday

Where presumably, 1 and 2 are interchangeable depending on the actual time difference.

This can definitely be done with MongoDB's aggregation framework. It works something as follows:

1. Match the documents that ended within a certain time period.
2. Project the difference between today and the end time of each event in a new field (say `timeDelta`).
3. Because MongoDB does not have an absolute operator for the aggregation framework, do some condition checking to get the absolute value of the time delta and project it to a new field, say `absTimeDelta`.
4. Sort by `absTimeDelta`.

So it should look something like this:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { '$match':
        { 'end':
            { '$gte': datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=3) } 
        }
    },
    { '$project':
        {
            'timeDelta': { 
                '$subtract': ['$end', datetime.utcnow()]
            }
        }
    },
    { '$project':
        {               
            'absTimeDelta' : { 
                '$cond' : [
                    { '$lte': ['$timeDelta', 0] },
                    { '$multiply' : ['$timeDelta', -1 ] },
                    '$timeDelta'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { '$sort':
        {
            'absTimeDelta' : 1
        }
    }
])
```

**EDIT**: In MongoDB version 3.2, [this JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10176) has been fixed, introducing the [`$abs` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/). This means that the second `$project` can be removed and the first one can be updated. Instead of `'$subtract': ['$end', datetime.utcnow()]` you can use `$abs: { '$subtract': ['$end', datetime.utcnow()] }`.

Comment: Awesome. Let me know if it worked well for you or if you had to make any changes. I thought it was an interesting problem to solve so I went ahead and tried it with a sample data set and it worked fine for me.

Comment: very minor detail - you may want to change the condition to `$lt`instead of `$lte`. If the delta is 0 there's no point doing any multiplication

Comment: another point - the first match of the query won't work outside Python. To achieve the same, you'll need to project the time difference first: `time_diff: { $subtract: [ISODate(), "$end"] }` followed by a match against it (time difference is given in milliseconds: 3*24*60*60*1000): `time_diff: { $lte: 259200000 }`

Comment: True about the `$lt` @guyarad. Regarding the Python syntax, indeed you would have to change those to suit your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way you can ask MongoDB to do this for you for now as [mongo does not support, for the moment, sorting using a function](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-153).

However if your range is always centered on the current day, why not updating a field every night, storing the timedelta between the current day and the event ? This way you'll be able to index it and sort on it. If you're keeping years of data, you may want to update only some weeks of data, to get a constant-time update, not growing with your data growth.